# Trying to get property of non-object at '(underscore)_view.php' in yii

Tags: php, sql, yii

i have relation between Operator and Level

table1(operator)
1.operator_id(pk)
2.operator_name
3.level_id(fk)

table2(level)
1.level_id(pk)
2.level_name

the relation on operator class :

public function relations()

```
{
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        'op_level'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Level', 'level_id'),
        );
    }
```

some of _view.php source code :

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('level_id')); ?> 
                       <?php $op_level = Level::model()->findByPK($data->level_id);?>
    <?php echo $op_level->level_name;?>
```

it keep says 'Trying to get property of non-object'
why it can't run smoothly ??, i have tried the relation and this method on the other project, and run smoothly , please help me to fix this

and this is the operator controller :

```
<?php

class OperatorController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
     * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Operator;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Operator']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Operator'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->operator_id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Operator']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Operator'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->operator_id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Operator');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Operator('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Operator']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Operator'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
     * @return Operator the loaded model
     * @throws CHttpException
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Operator::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param Operator $model the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='operator-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

index.php on protected/views/operator

```
<?php
/* @var $this OperatorController */
/* @var $dataProvider CActiveDataProvider */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Operators',
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'Create Operator', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('label'=>'Manage Operator', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<h1>Operators</h1>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

Comment: post your controller code.

Comment: okay edited few minutes ago

Comment: Are you calling index function in controller? If so, please add your index view file also

Comment: $op_level is not passed or declared in your file. what is that?

Comment: i just realized that the code are too positioned on the right, i just added some edit , on the view

Answer (score 0):

To get related table data,

Change code in controller as below:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Operator',

            array('criteria'=>array(
                             'with'=>array(
                                           'op_level'
                                          ),
                             'together'=>true,
                            )   
                 )     
         );
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }
```

In view

```
 <?php echo $data->op_level->level_name;?>
```

Comment: is that  $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Operator','criteria'=>array(
have a commas ?? , that have an error on the '=>'

Comment: Yes. It's typo mistake

Comment: uhm , kumar ? have you seen the declaration on $op_level on above ??

Comment: Yes. Try my code. This is the correct method. You dont want to create $op_level model object.

Comment: No. You dont want to add condition. Becaus you already mentioned in model relation function.

Comment: i mean that error = http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ABfsWGzdTWQ/UvnVaFrqRqI/AAAAAAAAA1Q/BwlvCKBfBRs/s1600/error1.jpg

Comment: did you remove code in view and add my code in _view?

Answer (score 0):

i may be found the solution just now, the field type isn't just integer, but it set by default from mysql : 0000000 caused by zerofill , i'am not really sure about that , but i was unchecked zerfofill on the operator_id field, then recreate the model with gii, and voila...